# Swift: getting user location based on geoJSON

Tags: ios, swift, geojson, cllocationmanager

Given a geoJSON representation of each US state (such as [found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130615162524/http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json)), along with user location coordinates (as available via CLLocationManager), what would be the best way to identify which state is the user in? What is the standard way to parse the geoJSON file, and simply identify which polygons contain the user location?

Let's say my location is in Indiana. I'm looking to create a function that parses the geoJSON representing the US, and identify that the user location only falls within the boundaries of Indiana coordinates.

Any suggestions/tips here is appreciated.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift

Comment: "what would be the best way to identify which state is the user in?"  What makes one way the best of all?